# RegExp get string inside string

Tags: regex, perl

Let presume we have something like this:

```
<div1>
    <h1>text1</h1>
    <h1>text2</h1>
</div1>
<div2>
    <h1>text3</h1>
</div2>
```

Using RegExp we need to get `text1` and `text2` but not `text3`.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
This is just an example.
The text I'm parsing could be just plain text.
The main thing I want to accomplish is list all strings from a specific section of a document.
I gave this HTML code for example as it perfectly resembles the thing I need to get.

`(?siU)<h1>(.*)</h1>` would parse all three strings, but how to get only first two?

**EDIT2:**
Here is another rather dumb example. :)

```
Section1

This is a "very" nice sentence.
It has "just" a few words.

Section2

This is "only" an example.

The End
```

I need quoted words from first but not from second section.

Yet again, `(?siU)"(.*)"` returns quoted words from whole text,
and I need only those between words `Section1` and `Section2`.

This is for the ["Rainmeter" application](http://rainmeter.net/RainCMS/?q=TipsAndTricksWebParserPrimer), which apparently uses Perl regex syntax.

I'm sorry, but I can't explain it better. :)

Comment: Number of <h1> ocurrences can be be any.

Comment: What criterion determines which content you want? What language are you programming in? Also, you really shouldn't use regexes to parse HTML.

Comment: Refer to this post on parsing html with Regex: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos:
Criterion can vary, but for first example, I need content inside <h1> tags from <div1> section. I'm not programming in any language, I'm only modifying my desktop with Rainmeter, which uses RegExp in for some parts. :) Nothing really important here.

Comment: you are making your question so vague, it is impossible to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case of the two examples provided -- for use in Rainmeter regex -- you can use:

`(?siU)<h1>(.*)</h1>(?=.+<div2>)` for the first sample and

`(?siU)"(.*)"(?=.+Section2)` for the second.

Note that Rainmeter seems to escape things for you, but you might need to change `"` to `\"`, above.

These both use [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) but beware: **both solutions will fail in the case of nested tags/structures or if there are mutiple Section1's and Section2's.   Regex is not the best tool for this kind of parsing.**

But maybe this is good enough for your current needs?

Comment: The thing is, there are nested tags and your solution doesn't work.
But by modifying it I managed to solve my problem.
`(?siU)<h1>(.*)</h1>.*(?=.+<div2>)` will work even if there are nested tags/structures.
Than you very much. I wouldn't be able to do it without your help. :D

Answer (score 2):

Use a DOM library and `getElementsByTagName('div')` and you'll get a nodeList back. You can reference the first item with `->item(0)` and then `getElementsByTagName('h1')` using the div as a context node, grab the text with `->nodeValue` property.

Comment: Ah, but he did not use `div` tags.  He used `div1` and `div2` (¿etc?).  :)

Comment: I take it he meant to do `div` but provided the numbers to indicate first, second. And he could also just do `getElementsByTagName` on h1 and grab the first 2 nodeValues in the nodeList.

Comment: Since number of `h1`'s varies, and I need all of them, grabbing only first two isn't the solution. As for `div1` and `div2` confusion, look at the second example to see what I need. :)